# How to materialize grouping transformations on kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When applying groupBy() or groupByKey() on your kafka streams you get a KGroupedStream object. Is it possible to materialize that object, maybe within a time-window, and write the grouped data to a topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your custom aggregator to materialize the groupedStream into a  KTable. It will have the grouped records in the list format. Later it can be published to the kafka topic.

```
KTable<K, ArrayList<V>> groupedTable = streamObject.groupByKey().aggregate(
            // Custom Initializer
            ArrayList::new,
            // aggregator
            (key, value, list) -> {
                list.add(value);
                return list;
            }, new ArrayListSerde<V>(serdeType), storageName);
groupedTable.through(newTopic);
// Or convert into stream and publish
groupedTable.toStream().to(newTopic);
```